# Styling Custom Checkbox with Image Not Appearing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying out HTML and CSS and am relatively new to the entire concept. I'm currently working on styling a custom checkbox using an image I made from Photoshop. I am not able to figure out why my image is not appearing when I set it this way.

HTML

```
<ul id="myUL" class="ulChecklist">
  <form action="/action_page.php">                   
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step1">Step 1</label>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step2">Step 2</label>                    
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step3">Step 3</label>                    
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
background: url(check.png) left center no-repeat;
}
```

This is the pre-checked image I want to add.
[image: Check Image I want to add]

This is the post-checked image I want to add.
[image: This is the post-checked image I want to add.]

As you can see, it isn't appearing.
[image]

Is something wrong with the way I write these codes? I've checked the following Lynda course link: https://www.lynda.com/HTML-tutorials/Styling-radio-buttons-check-boxes-images/612196/646907-4.html

But it isn't working out for me. I would greatly appreciate help from people! Thank you for taking your time to answer a noob's question!

Comment: first of all your html is invalid. and second.. could you show your folder structure with the files?

Comment: can you create a working snippet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```css
ul{
  list-style:none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiFBl.png) no-repeat 0 center;
  padding-left:60px;
  line-height:50px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCst2.png) no-repeat 0 center; 
}
.check-wrap{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL" class="ulChecklist">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <li>
      <div class="check-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instruction" id="Step1">
        <label for="Step1">Step 1</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="check-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instruction" id="Step2">
        <label for="Step2">Step 2</label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="check-wrap">
        <input type="checkbox" name="instruction" id="Step3">
        <label for="Step3">Step 3</label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works beautifully. I also figured out the problem I had, apparently even though the image was in the same folder, URL would not accept a name like 'check.png' solely. I am not sure what gave me that idea that it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path. Just that you need to resize the background image and `float` it to the left. And one of the most important part is to associate the label with the input checkbox with `for` and `id`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
opacity: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
background: url(http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i86039/graphicloads/100-flat-2/check-1.ico) left center no-repeat;
float: left;
padding-left: 25px; /*image width plus extra padding */
background-size: 20px 20px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
background: url(https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/2181-200.png) left center no-repeat;
float: left;
padding-left: 25px; /*image width plus extra padding */
background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="myUL" class="ulChecklist">
  <form action="/action_page.php">                   
    <li><input id="Step1" type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step1">Step 1</label>
    </li>
    <li><input id="Step2" type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step2">Step 2</label>                    
    </li>
    <li><input id="Step3" type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step3">Step 3</label>                    
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided makes no provision for the background `label` image when the adjacent sibling `pseudo-state` is `:checked`.

You'll need to account for both states, e.g: `input[type="checkbox"]` **&** `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {
background: url(check.png) left center no-repeat;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
background: url(check-alt.png) left center no-repeat;
}
```

*Edit*
You may also need to declare background size properties.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I am not able to view the Lynda course as I am not a member, but will do my best to answer this.

If I were setting up I would make the following changes to your code:

```
<ul id="myUL" class="ulChecklist">
  <form action="/action_page.php">                   
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="instruction">
      <label for="Step1">Step 1</label>
         <img src=“./check.png” class=“checkmark-section”>
    </li>
  </form>
</ul>
```

Then in the CSS I would callout the checkmark-section class and add in the click effect image under the pseudo class of focus < This is the css word for clicked.

For example:

.checkmark-section:focus {
       background: url(./checkmark-active)

}

This will mean that once checkmark-active is clicked, it will swap over to show the depressed check mark image instead. I have not tried this out, but that is how I would expect it to work.

All the best,

Dan